# the old ball and chain is dead?

Tags: phrase-meaning

[image]Who can tell me the meaning of "the old ball and chain is dead" by attachment? It is too hard to get the meaning of the old ball and chain is dead. I think it cannot be understood by words in general to get the meaning. Maybe it is an idiom.

Answer (score 3):

"Ball and chain" refers to a heavy iron ball that sometimes  used to be attached to a prisoner's ankle to prevent him from moving about easily. Nowadays it is used figuratively of something that limits a person's freedom, or jokingly of a man's wife.
https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/54950.html

Having seen your edit - yes, here it's an unkind reference to his late wife.

Comment: Kate Bunting.Thanks very much for your explanation.